# Scrapy: how to follow multiple links on a page using regex

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scraper which collects information perfectly, but when I try to implement rules to crawl the "next" page I get stuck. Using Scrapy 0.22 (I can't upgrade at this time).

```
import re
import datetime
import dateutil 
import urllib2

from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from crawlers.spiders import BaseCrawler


class rappSpider(BaseCrawler):
    name = "rapp"

    base_url = "www.example.com"
    start_urls = [
        # "http://www.example.com/news-perspective",
        # "http://www.example.com/news-perspective?f[0]=field_related_topics%3A31366",
        "http://www.example/news-perspective?key=&page=%d"

    ]
    # rules = [
         # Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'?key=&page=[0-9]'), callback='get_article_links', follow= True)
     # ]

    TITLE_XPATH_SELECTOR= "//div[@id='inset-content']//h1/text()"

    TEXT_XPATH_SELECTOR = "//div[@class='field-item even']/p/text()"

    DATETIME_XPATH_SELECTOR = "//div[@class='field-items']/div/span/text()"

    def get_article_links(self, response, *args, **kwargs):
        html = Selector(response)
        link_extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('http://www.example.com/news-perspective/\d{4}/\d{2}\/*\S*$',))

        is_relative_path = False
        yield [link.url for link in link_extractor.extract_links(response)], is_relative_path
```

The scraper works for start_urls like http://www.example/news-perspective which lists a number of articles on the page, then the scraper will follow the links defined by get_article_links and get the relevant information. However, I'd like to be able to go to the next page (same format on other pages, the url being

http://www.example/news-perspective?key=&page=**#**

How can I set this up with my existing code? Do I need two separate rules ? Or do I need to alter start_requests?

Comment: Would `^http://www.example/news-perspective?key=&page=\d+$` not work?

Answer (score 0):

In the website there is probably a "Next" button that links to the next page. You should include a rule that matches that link.